# Android startActivityForResult hide screen shot

Tags: android, android-activity, hide, screenshot

In Android, I call `startActivityForResult` to start another activity, which is an email intent, and I also want to hide the screen shot for this new activity from Android task manager.
I know usually use `Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure)` before `SetContentView` of Activity, but for the new activity from `startActivityForResult`, how to setup such flag?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

> which is an email intent

I am assuming that you mean "an `Intent` that will resolve to some third-party activity that happens to involve email".

> I also want to hide the screen shot for this new activity from Android task manager

You are not the author of the other app. The decision of whether the other app should appear or not appear in the task manager is up to the developer of the other app, not you.

If you need this degree of control, do not display any activities from third-party apps.

Comment: Since I have add secure flag to all the other activities, then the screen shot will take the screen of email no matter the email activity is complete or not, as the screen shot of task manager will take the last screen shot of activity which is not applied to secure flag. So the user will be confused for screen shot, is there any other solution to avoid it, such as customize the screen shot of the whole app? thx

Comment: @zhususui: "is there any other solution to avoid it" -- do not display any activities from third-party apps, as I wrote in my answer. "such as customize the screen shot of the whole app?" -- the third-party app **is not your app**. You cannot control whether or not it allows screenshots. The overview screen (a.k.a., recent-tasks list) shows *tasks* and whatever activity is at the top of those tasks. It does not show *apps*.